# what is the difference between these two lines

Tags: php, conditional-operator

getting 2 different outputs while using the same currency 'egp'

`$currency = ($q->currency == 'egp')? '£' : (($q->currency == 'usd') ? '$' : '€');`

this line outputs `$`

`$currency = ($q->currency == 'egp')? '£' : ($q->currency == 'usd') ? '$' : '€';`

this one outputs `£`

and I can't find why?

note: the only difference is the `()` around the second ternary operator statement

Comment: The removal of the extra () causes the precedence of the operators to change. If you need to do this kind of thing, I usually recommend switching to `if elseif else` standard syntax for ease of use, readability and understanding.

Comment: Ternary operations are awesome, for short and simple checks. Nested ternary operations should be illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
echo (true?"Left is first":(true?"Right is first":""));
```

> Left is first

Versus

```
echo (true?"Left is first":true?"Right is first":"");
```

> Right is first

The exaplanation can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary.

In short, in the second case PHP will evaluate `true?"Left is first":true` as the condition for the ternary expression. This will evaluate to `Left is first` which evaluates to true and therefore `Right is first` will be echoed